# iOS tableView multiple selection

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsuserdefaults, didselectrowatindexpath

Many of the ways and methods out there to select multiple rows is either deprecated or doesn't work.

I simply want to select multiple rows in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and save them into Array or `NSUserDefault`. This case I picked `NSUserDefault` but I am willing to change it to Array.

This is my code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NotificationsTableViewCell *cell = (NotificationsTableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //set clicked icon after row selected
    cell.imgIcon.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"select-icon"];

    //notification id for selected row
    Notifications* selected = notifications[indexPath.section];
    selectedGroup = selected.NotificationsId;

     //save it in nsuserdefaults
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:selectedGroup forKey:@"notificationSelectedID"];

}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

//deselect the row

}
```

**Note**: I am using latest Xcode SDK 8.

Thank you for your helps.

Comment: Doesn't work need clarification. What's your problem?

Comment: Approch is wrong logic is wrong what do you want with your attached code. you just need to IndexPath and save that indexpath in array or other place

Comment: @Eiko, i have a list of rows/items that i display, and an icon in each row. So i am supposed to be able to select multiple rows, and after each selection i change particular icon to checked mark. And i want to store the value i retrieve from row into NSArray. Thanks.

Comment: @NitinGohel as i explained above, i can choose one and store, but when i choose the next one, previous row will overwrite. Thanks.

Comment: As you can see you need to pick one array and as par my answer you need to add and remove as par selection item in array. and at the final you need to store in NSUserDefault.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate it below answer? I am not very clear about it and new to iOS.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

NotificationsTableViewCell *cell = (NotificationsTableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

 // do your logic with following condition

if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) 
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    } 
    else 
    {

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    }

}
```

Comment: this helped me to select multiple, but how can i save them into array without overwriting?

Comment: create one MutableArray and while select cell you needt to add your data in array like [MyArray addObject:yourData] and why you again select on selected row you can remove this bu [myArray removeObject:yourdata];

Comment: but when you add the next value, it will remove the first value. like: NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; then selectedGroup = selected.NotificationsId; and [myArray addObject:selectedGroup]; is saving, but when you click another cell myArray has 1 object again instead 2.

Comment: You really want a selected row (in UI terms) to show no checkmark? This might go wrong... Half of the logic here just belongs in tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: do not alloc array in didselect make it .h clas allow in viewdidLoad and use in didselect

Answer (score 0):

You can declare mutable array and when every time user selects particular row, add required detail for particular row in an array then use NSUserDefaults to store updated array.

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

```
[arrRows addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", indexPath]];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:arrRows forKey:@"arrRows"];
```

}

Comment: but when you add the next value, it will remove the first value. like: NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; then selectedGroup = selected.NotificationsId; and [myArray addObject:selectedGroup]; is saving, but when you click another cell myArray has 1 object again instead 2.

Comment: No do not initialise mutable array inside didSelect..Initialize it in either viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear